# Vim Session keeping terminal state

Tags: terminal, tmux, sessions, terminal-buffer

[image]

I am currently using tmux to have two terminals on the left and vim on the right. One terminal is running Django server, and the other one is for general usage.

I am trying to find out if I can ditch tmux and use vim/neovim sessions as a solution.

Is there a way for a vim session to automatically change to a specific directory, enable a virtualenv and start the server as I am currently doing with tmux?

Comment: Your title and question text seem different. Are you trying to save the terminal state like tmux's 'detach?'  Or, to just re-run the same command at vim start-up?

Comment: @Mass When I rerun the tmux session it keeps the state of the django server running etc. I am asking if there's a way to save that state in the vim session, so when I come back and source it will automatically do all the things I said above (change working dir, enable virtualenv, start the server).

Comment: I believe vim sessions can store the pwd, but to enable virtualenv/launch a server would require shelling out and is probably more easily accomplished using a plugin (whether one out there or a simple script you write yourself)

Answer (score 1):

According to `:h terminal-session` it will relaunch a terminal buffer with a session by running the command which was supplied to `:terminal` to start with or you can modify it via `term_setrestore()`.

> Is there a way for a vim session to automatically change to a specific directory, enable a virtualenv and start the server as I am currently doing with tmux?

I do not use `:terminal` or such a setup as you do, but I would hazard a guess that you could create a shell/python script which would change your current directory, enable virtualenv, and start your server. Combine it with a custom Vim command to execute it:

```
command! StartServer execute "terminal start-server.sh " . resolve(expand('%:h'))
```

In theory doing something like this would allow it restore. That being said if you now have a nice command to start your server, you may not care as much if it restores as you can easily access it.

For more help see:

```
:h terminal
:h term_setrestore
:h :execute
:h resolve()
:h expand()
:h :terminal
```